# Object change direction after collide with controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity3D I have got a gameobject that is attached with a box collider and physic material. The hand controller model is also attached to a box collider and physic material. When the gameobject collides with the hand controller, the `CollideWithController` logs on the console. However, the gameobject does not change direction.

```
if (other.CompareTag("HandController")) 
{
    Debug.Log("CollideWithController");
    var magnitude = 1000;
    var force = transform.position - other.transform.position;
    force.Normalize();
    gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(force * magnitude);
}
```

Comment: Please post your code as actual code, not as screenshot. See the [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for formatting instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing/knowing what `other` is, its hard to say, but generally there could be two problems:

1. `transform.position-other.transform.position` doesn't actually result in the direction you expect. To determine this, print the value or display it using `Debug.DrawRay`.
2. The force you're adding might not be enough to change direction, or there are other forces canceling it out.

Comment: 'other' would refer to the hand controller which i would like the controller to interact with. I have tried to change the force but still no result. Actually I realized i did not set a new direction for the gameobject to move to? Sorry, I am pretty new to coding so this code was what i referenced from others.

Answer (score 0):

```
var force = transform.position - other.transform.position;
```

You will get a direction vector to get other to the position of this. So you are moving into the collision, reversing the vector should fix your issue.

Comment: What do you mean by reversing the vector? is it var force = other.transform.position - transform.position? 
I have tried this reversing of the vector, but the object still doesnt change direction?

Comment: By reversing I mean multiplying by -1 after or before you normalize it.

Answer (score 0):

When you modify physics value like here with AddForce, you should do it in the FixedUpdate to minimize the risk of bug. (It can work outside of the FixedUpdate, but in most case it will create unwanted behavior).

In your code you use AddFroce, but if the actual force of the gameObject is greater than this the force you add will just slow the actual movement of the gameobject and not reverse it.

I think the best way to change the movement of your gameObject is to use the velocity vector and to reflect it.

One more advice : Don't use physics for gameplay system. Physics is something very powerfull, it can bring a lot of emergent behavior, but it's a chaotic system. And when it's about gameplay you don't want chaos you want control and consistency.

Unity doc :

- Velocity : [https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Reflect.html)
- Reflect : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Reflect.html